# Run a build with qa-report plugin enabled to see results here

Tags: testing, jenkins, automated-tests, jenkins-plugins, web-testing

I start a new job in jenkins ci configured as free-style. I add post-build action "qa-report" and "Publish JUnit test result report". But I dont get qa-report and test result trend chart. I dont have the prevelige to access master machine. Cases are worked restrictly on a node. I can access the node.

[image]

For qa-report, I get the information.

```
Run a build with qa-report plugin enabled to see results here
```

What should I do? Does free-style not enabled qa-report? Do I need to specify some files or paths which located on master? Is there something wrong with the edition of maven. I am using maven3X. What kind of path of the [xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731146/jenkins-test-result-trend-graph-empty-but-tests-are-run) should I input to get chart. Any idea and references would be appreciated.

**Expected:**

1 qa-report

[image]

2 test result chart

[image]